# TeX definitions of `` and ''

Tags: plain-tex, ligatures

Where and how does TeX define the character sequence `` and '' ?

From the TeX * prompt, how does one "show" the definition?

Comment: @egreg The problem is I never would have searched for the answer with anything from that question.  I suspect I'm not the only one.

Comment: Closing this one as duplicate doesn't mean it's removed. The answer there covers this case.

Comment: Understood.  And I agree that this question's answer is a "subset" of the answer provided in the other question.

Comment: Closing as duplicate is not a judgement on the question's value. Just a way to keep information as tight as possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't. `\show` shows definitions at the macro layer but ``` `` ``` is implemented as a *ligature* and becomes an open double quote the same way that `ff` becomes an ff ligature.
Thus the information is defined *per font* in the font metrics.

so the nearest you can do is:

```
$ tex
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=tex)
**\setbox0\hbox{``}\showbox0
> \box0=
\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x5.00002
.\tenrm \ (ligature ``)

! OK.
<*> \setbox0\hbox{``}\showbox0

?
```